# Sequelize: passing Sequelize.op.in where

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am creating **where** dynamically for my model. I want to use **in** for multiple values. I read documentation and online and found this:

```
Patient.findAll({
    limit: limit,
    offset: offset,
    where: {
        [Sequelize.Op.in]: patientIds
    }
 });
```

I want to build **where** something like this:

```
var filter = {
   [Sequelize.Op.in]: patientIds,
   is_active: filter.is_active
};

Patient.findAll({
    limit: limit,
    offset: offset,
    where: filter
});
```

I also tried:

```
const op = Sequelize.Op;
const operatorsAliases = {
    $in: op.in
};
```

and then:

```
var filter = {
   operatorsAliases.$in: patientIds,
   is_active: filter.is_active
};
```

But in both cases, it gives me error:

```
TypeError: s.replace is not a function
at Object.removeTicks (F:\Codes\medical_tourism\node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils.js:415:12)
at Object.quoteIdentifier (F:\Codes\medical_tourism\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query-generator.js:393:33)
at Object._getSafeKey (F:\Codes\medical_tourism\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2298:33)
at Object._joinKeyValue (F:\Codes\medical_tourism\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2274:16)
at Object._whereParseSingleValueObject (F:\Codes\medical_tourism\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2332:23)
at Object.whereItemQuery (F:\Codes\medical_tourism\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2090:19)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What's the value of `patientIds`?

Comment: Array of integers

Comment: Make sure to console.log(typeof(patientIds) and console.log(patientIds) right before patientIds to make absolutely sure the data you are expectiing is correct.

Answer (score 19):

You are missing the column on which you want to filter.
Assuming 'id' is the column you want to filter, the code would look like:

```
Patient.findAll({
    limit: limit,
    offset: offset,
    where: {
        id: {
            [Sequelize.Op.in]: patientIds
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try AND if you want two conditions to be true like this:

```
Patient.findAll({
  limit: limit,
  offset: offset,
  where: {
    [Sequelize.Op.and]: [{
      [Sequelize.Op.in]: patientIds
    }, {
      is_active: filter.is_active
    }]
  }
});
```

And if you wish to have only one condition to be true you can us 'OR' instead of 'AND'